# Smartcontract failed (created by scam hacker). Status reverted. Is money gone? please advice

Tags: smart-contract-wallets

I hope someone can make me a bit wiser because i got scammed by an eth hacker. He promised to help me with another scam. it's a simple case an really appreciate honest advice.

This is the smart contract
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x9a57c94e1257a743a2635fb35f3b10330071ed17b92e4f7c35f8577b168e817b
on the from field is my wallet. When you click on that you see transfers to the hackers wallet.

Can this be reversed because the smartcontract is failed?
Any other advice in getting moneyback?

THANKS VERY MUCH for every info

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but no. The failed transaction has no relation to the other transactions that have sent ether to the scammer. Although you tried to execute the `transfer` function, you can see that the address you sent the ether to is not a smart contract. It is simply a user account (EOA), and the user has already continued to use your funds. So your funds are gone.